# Switch case en PHP con variable

Tags: php, telegram

Mi duda es la siguiente, estoy realizando un bot de Telegram con ayuda al usuario en diversos casos. Me gustaría captar un trozo del mensaje que me envía para utilizarlo como variable, es decir:

```
switch($mensaje)
 case '/tiempo Madrid':
    $ciudad="Madrid";
    $horas=FALSE;
    getTiempo($chatId,$ciudad,$horas);
    break;
```

En este caso me gustaría no tener que escribir en el case directamente la ciudad, si no hacer una especie de `/tiempo $ciudad`, cuya variable `$ciudad` pueda utilizar para llamar a la función `getTiempo()` y así no tener que escribir una a una todas las ciudades del mundo como diferentes case.

Es decir, algo así:

```
switch($mensaje)
 case '/tiempo $ciudad':
    $horas=FALSE;
    getTiempo($chatId,$ciudad,$horas);
    break;
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: mira esta info en php http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.variable.php, puedes ocupar variables variables. espero sirva saludos.

Comment: No sé si te entendí bien, si quieres que en el case, varíe el nombre de la ciudad, entonces puedes hacer case '/tiempo '.$ciudad y definir la variable $ciudad por fuera del switch.

Comment: Lo edité por si así se entendía mejor, sería como capturar la ultima palabra del mensaje para utilizarla en la función

Comment: Osea, lo que quieres es generar dinamicamente multiples case, sin tener que escribir uno a uno?

Comment: En efecto, para no tener que escribir cada ciudad del mundo, poder generar un case que almacene el nombre de la ciudad que es la última parte de $mensaje en la variable $ciudad y pueda utilizarse en la función a la que llamo.

Comment: @EvelynGarcía en la respuesta te ofrezco una alternativa a lo que buscas, funcionaria para lo que necesitas, después de todo un switch no es mas que la ejecución de multiples if. En el caso de mi respuesta, estos if se generan con un foreach

Comment: La mejor forma de hacer esto sería mediante un array... O si se quiere más profesionalidad, mediante una base de datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No creo que se pueda hacer el switch con doble variable, pero mira esta alternativa:
- Sugiero que separes el comando del mensaje, de esa forma podrás obtener los datos por separado y hacer lo que quieras con ellos.

```
    $mensaje = explode(' ', $mensajeUsuario, 2);
    // $mensaje[0]: Representa el comando
    // $mensaje[1]: Representa el mensaje o la otra variable que tu quieres
    switch($mensaje[0])
     case '/tiempo':
        $ciudad = $mensaje[1];
        $horas=FALSE;
        getTiempo($chatId,$ciudad,$horas);
        break;
```

Comment: ¡Era justo lo que necesitaba! Muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

la verdad no conozco una manera de generar dinamicamente los case de un switch, pero creo que tal vez esta alternativa te pueda ayuda. Simplemente defines un array con todas las ciudades (en tu caso imagino que pueden venir de una base de datos), luego recorres el array y vas comparando la ciudad del array con la del mensaje, una vez la encuentra, se ejecuta el codigo del if y se detiene el bucle.

```
$ciudades = ['Madrid', 'Londres', 'Lima'];

$mensaje = '/tiempo Londres';

foreach($ciudades as $ciudad){
    $comparar = '/tiempo '.$ciudad;
    if($mensaje == $comparar){
        $horas=FALSE;
        echo $ciudad;
        getTiempo($chatId,$ciudad,$horas);
        break;//Evitar que el bucle siga la ejecución una vez se encuentre la ciudad
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda pero debo hacerlo con un switch..